# Extend annotated controllers in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

i am working on a small project and have some existing code which I want to keep clean from my changes and therefore I need to extend a annotated controller but this does not work:

```
package a;

@controller
public class BaseController {
    // Autowired fields

    protected x toExtend() {
         // do stuff
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/start")
    protected ModelAndView setupForm(...) {
        toExtend();
        // more stuff
    }
}



package b;

@controller
public class NewController extends BaseController {
    // Autowired fields

    @Override
    protected x toExtend() {
         super.toExtend();
         //new stuff
    }
}
```

Package a and b are scanned for controllers and i cannont change this. I did not really expect this to work because the @RequestMapping(value = "/start") is redundant in both controllers. And I get an exception because of this.

So my question is whether it is actually possible to extend a annotation driven controller like this without changing the BaseController?

Comment: It should work if you remove `@Controller` annotation from your `BaseController`, unless there is a reason to have to maintain it there too.

Comment: You should not have `super.toExtend();` in your base class. There is no `super` method called `toExtend()` since the parent class is `Object`.

Comment: yes you are right this is a copy paste error and i edited it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can extend one spring controller by another spring controller.

When a Spring MVC controller extends another Controller, the functionality of the base controller can be directly used by the child controller using the request URL of the child controller. You can get more details here [Extending Spring controllers](http://www.kscodes.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-controller-extends-another-controller/)

Comment: This seems to be a good solution - Remapping the base URL the controller uses is quite simple :)

Answer (score 2):

If `BaseController`'s annotation cannot be removed, then you can use [Adapter Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) to obtain the inheritance.

```
@Controller
public class NewController {
    // Autowired fields
    BaseController base;

    protected x toExtend() {
         base.toExtend();
         //new stuff
    }
}
```

In usual cases, either `BaseController` does not have `@Controller` annotation, hence common controller methods can be put inside `BaseController` to be extended by **actual controllers**

Comment: The Adapter Pattern would require to change the toExtend() from protected to public. It seems its not possible to completly leave the BaseController as it is and i think i will remove the @controller because it seems to be the way with the "easiest" to reproduce changes in case of updates.