# Seeing NoSuchMethodExceptions with spring annotations

Tags: java, spring, exception, annotations, spring-annotations

I have an application that I support, and when I took a JFR of it running I noticed it was throwing hundreds of exceptions per second, but otherwise working fine. I'd like to know the reasons for these exceptions.

I have the following code (I'm not a developer, just a server admin):

```
 sidebar.java contains:
@Controller
public class sidebarController

 vfolder.java contains:
@Controller
public class vfolderController extends sidebarController

 claim.java: contains:
@Controller
public class claimController extends sidebarController
```

The exceptions I'm seeing thrown and captured at runtime are from `AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation`, and are all for methods that are in vfolder and claim, but the exception message says it's looking for methods in the sidebar class i.e. `com.company.sidebarController.randomVFolderFunction(java.lang.String)` instead of looking in `com.company.vfolder`. How should I proceed? Is this by design? I can't imagine it's supposed to be throwing this many exceptions. Example stack trace:

```
Exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodException "com.company.sidebarController.randomVFolderFunction(java.lang.String)"
java.lang.Throwable.<init>(String)
java.lang.Exception.<init>(String)
java.lang.ReflectiveOperationException.<init>(String)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException.<init>(String)
java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod.<init>(String, Class[])
org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(Method, Class)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter$ServletHandlerMethodInvoker.getModelAndView(Method, Class, Object, ExtendedModelMap, ServletWebRequest)
...
```

Is this because of the vfolder and claim classes extending sidebar? I'm just wondering what direction I could point a developer in regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

try to remove @Controller from vfolderController and claimController

sidebar.java contains:

```
@Controller
public class sidebarController
```

vfolder.java contains:

```
public class vfolderController extends sidebarController
```

claim.java: contains:

```
 public class claimController extends sidebarController
```

or [Abstract Controller](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-abstract-controller-example/)

Comment: I did some more reading on extending controllers, and a comment in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15907494/extend-annotated-controllers-in-spring-mvc suggested that the extended classes should have @Controller, and not the base class. Not that I know the implications, I'd just like a possible explanation behind the reasoning here that I can pass on to devs.